# splitting List<Object> based on the value of a variable in that Object

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to split my list into multiple smaller lists but don't know how i should do it.

```
List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
```

This is my original list that contains the object Object. I am trying to split this list based on the variables of this Object.

example:

```
public class Object {
   string var1;
   int var2;
   int var3;
}
```

lets say the list Object has 3 possible var1 ("yes","no","maybe") then i want 3 Lists where each list are all the objects that have "yes","no" or "maybe" as var1 (this can be a list of 100 objects long with each object being one of this string) (the amount of possibilities in var1 is not constant)

Comment: You mean you want a list of strings, ints and ints respectively to be a list of var1's, var2's, and var3's?

Comment: did you mean like group in SQL?? here also you can use `GroupBy` linq

Comment: lets say the list Object has 3 possible var1 ("yes","no","maybe") then i want 3 Lists where each list are all the objects that have "yes","no" or "maybe" as var1 (this can be a list of 100 objects long with each object being one of this string)

Comment: Cool see answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you will have splitted list of your object. you can use group by your property of your class. something like.

```
var splittedList = list.GroupBy(c=>c.var1).Select(c => c.ToList()).ToList() ;
```

Here splittedList is type of `List<List<YourObject>>`  So for your `Yes, No, MayBe` case it will return list of 3 List. and each of these three  will contains object with same `var1` property

Comment: Perfect, this did it for me, thnx! Will accept the answer when i can!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ILookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var splitted = list.ToLookup(item => item.var1);
```

Comment: Agree. Lookups are _generally_ more usable than a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Linq:

```
List<Object> listYes = list.Where(o => o.var1 == "yes").ToList();
List<Object> listNo = list.Where(o => o.var1 == "no").ToList();
List<Object> listMaybe = list.Where(o => o.var1 == "maybe").ToList();
```

This will give you 3 lists of objects where var1 equals the respective valuein the `Where()` clause.

Comment: and now an add on, what if i do not know the variables of var1, it could be 4 whole different possibilities?

Comment: The other answer answered my question, but thnx for the possibility!

Comment: Yeah I agree with Dmitry Bychenko and Deepak Sharma. Could go either way, depends what you are going to do with the data afterwards as to what would work best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
            List<Object> list1 = new List<Object>();
            List<Object> list2 = new List<Object>();

            for (int i=0;i<list.Count;i++)
            {
                if (list.var1 == 0)
                {
                    list1.Add(list[i]);
                }
                if (list.var1 == 1)
                {
                    list2.Add(list[i]);
                }

            }
```